# Why is the plural of "braccio" and "avambraccio" different, even though the latter word derives from the former?

Tags: plural, grammatical-number

The plural of *braccio* is *braccia*, and the plural of *avambraccio* is *avambracci*.

Why are the plural of those words so different, if they both are referring to parts of the human body, and *avambraccio* derives from *braccio*?

Comment: The question sounds familiar: isn't it one of those which I offered as possible questions for this site? Where could I find my other questions so as to ask them? The original page seems not to be available any longer...

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949?phase=definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, some words have two plurals, and there's no general rule about them. In the case of *braccio*, it can be related to human body, or to something else (e.g. *i bracci del lampadario*).

The same applies to a lot of other words, such as *grido*, *filo*, *corno*, etc.

There is no other meaning for *avambracci*, so there's no need for a different plural form.

So, *bracci* actually exists as plural, but I believe that a slightly different version (*braccia*) found its space in language to mark in a stronger way the different meaning.

Anyway, I don't know the exact reason why speaking about the human body *braccia* has been chosen instead of *bracci*. Also, a legit question would be why it applies to plural but not to the singular word, which is the same for different meanings.

Further information:
http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/plurali-doppi

Comment: There is some kind of rule (two of them, actually) about the nouns with two different plurals. Some of them refer to names of body parts which also have a different, inanimate meaning (braccio, ciglio, corno); in the first case the plural is in “-a”, while in the second it is in “-i”. Other nouns have two plural according to they being considered one by one (“-i”) or collectively (“-a”): grido, budello, filo, dito, cervello, lenzuolo...